# Using Div's instead of anchors

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, anchor

On my website, www.funpunks.com, in the top left of the page you'll see the navigation. I made this using fixed-size div's with background images, and using javascript to redirect "window.location = 'http://www.funpunks.com/' " etc.

But what about for users who have thier javascript disabled etc? I think I need to use anchor tags.

I need these anchor tags to display as block, and I need them to have a background image. Also each different link needs to have its own height/width and hover image.

Could it be done with using anchor tags instead of divs?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you still use anchors but display them as block-level elements with CSS?

```
a.some-class { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitely want to use <a>'s here. Go for the semantic markup every time. Just do style="display:block" and set the width, height, background image etc. For example, take a look at one of my sites here: http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/. The tabs on the left and top are both a's, styled properly.

Answer (score 1):

an A tag can have it's height / width set through CSS just like everything else.

Comment: Gracias. I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote the original.